# pointer to std::vector of arbitrary type (or any other templated class)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, vector

let's say i want to have a member variable for a pointer to std::vector but i do not want to specify what type of variable it stores. I want to access only those functions that are independant of it's actual generic type. is this possible with c++? something like this:

```
class Foo{
public:
    void setVec(std::vector* someVec){
        myVec = someVec;
    };
    int getSize(){
        return myVec.size();
    };
private:
    std::vector* myVec;
};


int main(){
    Foo foo;
    vector<int> vec1;
    vector<float> vec2;
    foo.setVec(&vec1);
    cout<<foo.getSize();
    foo.setVec(&vec2);
    cout<<foo.getSize();
}
```

note: i do not want to template Foo and i want to use only a single instance of Foo with vectors of different type.

of course - if I could alter the class vector then i could create an untemplated baseclass

```
class Ivector{
    virtual int size()=0;
};
```

and then make the

```
class vector<T> : public IVector...
```

inherit from Ivector. but what do I do if i can't alter the class in question and the templated class does not have such an untemplated baseclass?

thanks!

Comment: Obligatory *why?* Please ask for help with the problem you're trying to solve, not the step you think you need to take to solve it.

Comment: curiosity. I'm learning about what things are possible with templated classes. so Now i want to know whether I can have pointers to templated classes if I don't know theyr template type.

Comment: A template class isn't a class type, it's instantiations are. It's difficult to answer an undirected question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost at the answer. Instead of making std::vector inherit from Ivector, create a new class:

```
template <typename T>
class IVectorImpl : public Ivector
{
public:
    explicit IVectorImpl(std::vector<T> * Data) : m_Data(Data){}
    std::vector<T> * m_Data;
 ...
     virtual int size() const {return m_Data->size();}
  // Implement all the Ivector functions here to call the respective functions off of m_Data
};
```

Now have your Foo class keep a pointer to Ivector instead of std::vector.

Make Foo::setVec templated

```
template <typename T>
void setVec(std::vector<T> * vec)
{
   Ivector * newVec = new IVectorImpl<T>(vec);
   delete myVec;
   myVec = newVec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
class vector_container_base
{
public:
    ~vector_container_base() {}

    virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class vector_container :
    public vector_container_base
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<T> vector_type;

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return mVector.size();
    }

private:
    vector_type mVector;
};
```

And so on, but I doubt this is too useful in any real situation.

Comment: hey that's actually quite neat! didn't think of capsulating it. it however still poses the effort of creating a special class for it. but it's a working workarround - thx :)

Comment: @Mat: Work around *for what*?

Comment: old, ugly & uncommented code that used to work a year ago but doesn't do so anymore. thank you! =)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
std::vector* myVec
```

is not syntactically correct. One has to specify the type of the vector elements.

You **may** want to do something on the line of

```
template< typename T >
class Foo{
  private:
    std::vector<T> * myVec;
};
```

However, even that doesn't look nice, re-evaluating the design might be more important here.

Comment: yes i know that. but the point is that I wouldn't want to templatize Foo. I could store the pointer instead as void* - but then i had no chance to call .size() even though i knew it's a pointer to a vector (but i wouldn't know a pointer to a vector of what type)