# Mapping vectors of arbitrary type

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap, boost-any

I need to store a list vectors of different types, each to be referenced by a string identifier. For now, I'm using `std::map` with `std::string` as the key and `boost::any` as it's value (example implementation [posted here](https://gist.github.com/2587386)).

I've come unstuck when trying to run a method on all the stored vector, e.g.:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any>::iterator it;
for (it = map_.begin(); it != map_.end(); ++it) {
  it->second.reserve(100);  // FAIL: refers to boost::any not std::vector
}
```

My questions:

- Is it possible to cast `boost::any` to an arbitrary vector type so I can execute its methods?
- Is there a better way to map vectors of arbitrary types and retrieve then later on with the correct type?

At present, I'm toying with an alternative implementation which replaces `boost::any` with a pointer to a base container class as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983814/pointer-to-stdvector-of-arbitrary-type-or-any-other-templated-class/3983859#3983859). This opens up a whole new can of worms with other issues I need to work out. I'm happy to go down this route if necessary but I'm still interested to know if I can make it work with `boost::any`, of if there are other better solutions.

*P.S. I'm a C++ <strike>n00b</strike> novice (and have been spoilt silly by Python's dynamic typing for far too long), so I may well be going about this the wrong way. Harsh criticism (ideally followed by suggestions) is very welcome.*

---

#### The big picture:

As pointed out in comments, this may well be an XY problem so here's an overview of what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm writing a task scheduler for a simulation framework that manages the execution of tasks; each task is an elemental operation on a set of data vectors. For example, if `task_A` is defined in the model to be an operation on `"x"(double), "y"(double), "scale"(int)` then what we're effectively trying to emulate is the execution of `task_A(double x[i], double y[i], int scale[i])` for all values of `i`.

Every task (function) operate on different subsets of data so these functions share a common function signature and only have access to data via specific APIs e.g. `get_int("scale")` and `set_double("x", 0.2)`.

In a previous incarnation of the framework (written in C), tasks were scheduled statically and the framework generated code based on a given model to run the simulation. The ordering of tasks is based on a dependency graph extracted from the model definition.

We're now attempting to create a common runtime for all models with a run-time scheduler that executes tasks as their dependencies are met. The move from generating model-specific code to a generic one has brought about all sorts of pain. Essentially, I need to be able to generically handle heterogenous vectors and access them by "name" (and perhaps `type_info`), hence the above question.

I'm open to suggestions. Any suggestion.

Comment: This look to me like a classic case of the [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). What you're trying to do is simply a very poor fit with C++. You probably need to step back a bit and tell us what you're really trying to accomplish. Right now, however, it appears (at least to me) that you're not writing C++; you're writing Python with C++ syntax.

Comment: I would concur. You certainly can't do what you want with `boost::any` without a lot of nasty jumping through hoops to keep track of exactly what kind of vector is stored in each slot, so this would be time to step back and look at the entire problem again because chances are you're using the wrong data type. Actually that's usually the case whenever `any` starts to look like a possibility. It has its place, but it's not a big one.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I concur too. It certainly feels like I'm going against the grain of the language with stumbling blocks at every turn I take. I'll see what I can do about describing the big picture - I'm wary about turning this into a *"this is my problem, design a solution for me"* question which may well be too involved and likely off-topic for [so].

Comment: @JerryCoffin I've added some overview of what I'm trying to attempt. Hope it helps. (p.s. I'm going offline soon but will address all feedback as soon as I can)

Comment: It looks like you don't need to keep all vectors in the same map. Why not have one map per type?

Comment: @n.m. Unfortunately, the list of types is not known in advance and not limited to primitive types. I did consider a map of maps but that got very convoluted very quickly.

Comment: @matthew I agree that with your sentiments and i was uncomfortable with my reliance on `boost::any` hence the scream for help which is this question.

Comment: «list of types is not known in advance» — list of types is **always** known in advance. Any program can work with a fixed set of types only. You cannot create new types at runtime. If the types are not known to the framework, they are known to the user of the framework. In the latter case, let the user tell your framework which types to use.

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough. I'll rephrase that - I need to handle arbitrary numbers of different types so explicitly creating one map per type may not be an option. The framework will expose routines for users to register their types and names of vectors using that type.

Comment: To use N types, you need O(N) lines of code just to declare the C API. You have to explicitly create *something* per type. If you do what Jerry Coffin suggests, you don't have to create the maps explicitly. You still have to create the C API explicitly, *no matter what C++ solution you use*.

Comment: Agreed. We do have the advantage that each C-driven model goes through a parse phase before the functions are compiled, so this is where we generate model-specific C APIs. The scheduler that runs the functions does not have this luxury.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the added detail, my immediate reaction would be to separate the data out into a number of separate maps, with the type as a template parameter. For example, you'd replace `get_int("scale")` with `get<int>("scale")` and `set_double("x", 0.2)` with `set<double>("x", 0.2);`

Alternatively, using `std::map`, you could pretty easily change that (for one example) to something like `doubles["x"] = 0.2;` or `int scale_factor = ints["scale"];` (though you may need to be a bit wary with the latter -- if you try to retrieve a nonexistent value, it'll create it with default initialization rather than signaling an error).

Either way, you end up with a number of separate collections, each of which is homogeneous, instead of trying to put a number of collections of different types together into one big collection.

If you really do need to put those together into a single overall collection, I'd think hard about just using a struct, so it would become something like `vals.doubles["x"] = 0.2;` or `int scale_factor = vals.ints["scale"];`

At least offhand, I don't see this losing much of anything, and by retaining static typing throughout, it certainly seems to fit better with how C++ is intended to work.

Comment: I probably should have added that 1) the access APIs need to be available to C functions as well for legacy reasons hence the avoidance of template parameters, and 2) the types are not limited to primitives and can be user-defined datatypes so I'll still need to manage my collection of maps if I keep them homogenous. Anyway, I'll mull over you suggestions and work it out when I get back to my desk in the morning. Many thanks for your input.