# Storing elements with different types into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, types

How can I store elements of different types in an array? 
The example below can lead to problems, because "wheels" can use 32-bit in an 8-bit array, so it fills the first 4 fields (if I understood it right). Can I use a shift operator << to overcome this problem, or is there an even better way to do it?

```
class Car
{
    public:
        Car();
        ~Car();

    private:
        int32 wheels;             // 32 bit Integer
        bool canDrive;            // 1 bit Boolean
        int16 doors;              // 16 bit Integer
}

Car()
{
    wheels = 4;
    canDrive = true;
    doors = 2;
}

int main()
{
    Car testCar;
    int08 tmpArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 0 };   //8-bit Integer array

    tmpArray[0] = testCar.wheels;         //Store 32-bit Integer into 8-bit Integer
    tmpArray[1] = testCar.canDrive;       //Store 1-bit Boolean into 8-bit Integer
    tmpArray[2] = testCar.doors;          //Store 16-bit Integer into 8-bit Integer

    /* Do something with tmpArray */       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It won't "use 32 bits in 8-bit" anything. The value will be converted, with possible loss of data.

Comment: do you want to insert a car in an array of ints?

Comment: C and C++ arrays can only hold elements of the same type. If you need just to get bytes representing `testCar` structure (to dump it on disk in binary form for example) you may use `int08 const * p_test_car_bytes = reinterpret_cast< int08 const * >(::std::addressof(testCar));`

Comment: If you think that a wheels can be stored in a `int08` type, just change wheels declaration to be `int08`.

Comment: Do you want to serialize Car into `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code - do you simply want an array of `Car`?

> How can I store elements of different types in an array?

Use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or `boost::variant`.  As an example, assuming that you want an array of either `int` or `float`:

```
using i_or_f = std::variant<int, float>;
std::array<i_or_f, 5> arr;
arr[0] = i_or_f{5};
arr[1] = i_or_f{0.4f};
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Your testCar is not constructed properly. No data has been assigned to wheelsm, canDrive, ... . Thus, setting other values with this undefined data will lead to undefined behavior.

2.) Your member values of the class car are private (This is a nice thing, since it ensures your data encapsulation). You will not be able to access them as you like.

3.) You can do a typecast form your different type. But why would you do so. You are loosing the [type safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

4.) Can you please explain, what is the purpose in storing your class members in an array. If you do not like to worry about the actual type consider using [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983814/pointer-to-stdvector-of-arbitrary-type-or-any-other-templated-class) is also worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I store elements of different types in an array?

Use polymorphism.

Create an std::vector of base class pointers.

```
std::vector<Car_t*> carVec;
```

Create pointers to derived instances and install in vector. Each derived instance is a different type.

```
carVec.push_back(new Derived_A_FromCar);
carVec.push_back(new Derived_B_FromCar);
carVec.push_back(new Ferrai_t);
carVec.push_back(new Fairlane_t);
... etc
```